# Не работает и не отображается JS код на странице

Tags: php, javascript

Есть такой код, который выводит `iframe` на странице из БД:

```
<?php 
    include 'header.php';

    //Тут связь с БД есть
    $result = mysqli_query($mySQL, $SQL);

    while($set = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<iframe src=\"".$set['link']."\" style=\"border: 0px; width: 950px; height: 500px\" webkitallowfullscreen=\"true\" mozallowfullscreen=\"true\">";
        echo "<script>alert('test'); document.title = 'title изменён!';</script>";
    }

    mysqli_close($mySQL);

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">alert('test'); document.title = 'title изменён!';</script>
    <?php

    include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Но какими бы я способам не выводил бы `JS` код, он даже не вставляется в код страницы(я не дурак, проверил, версия сохранена и опубликована). Почему такое может происходить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте закрывающий тэг: `echo "<iframe ...></iframe>"`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

> both the starting and ending tag are mandatory.
>
> как открывающий так и закрывающий тэги - обязательны.

Comment: Спасибо, не догадался сразу, ведь все работало и вычислить сложно было